# How to remove the ready to install interface, using Inno Setup?

Tags: typescript, interface, inno-setup, display, uninstallation

The script adds the following settings to the interface displayed by all Inno setups themselves:

```
[Setup]   
DisableDirPage=yes
DisableFinishedPage=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
DisableReadyMemo=yes
DisableStartupPrompt=yes
DisableWelcomePage=yes
DisableReadyPage=yes
```

But the ready to install interface is still displayed, how to remove the ready to install interface??

Comment: What's provoking the question? (If your aim is to make an install run without any prompting, you can't. You need the `/SILENT` parameter for that.)

Comment: The effect I want to achieve is that this interface can be not displayed as needed in the case of a non-silent installation.

Comment: @ Martin Prikryl ，Thank you for your answer. but.,Remind unknown identifier 'KillTimer' .....

Comment: The code from the answer to the linked question won't give you that error. We cannot help you without [mcve].